# I don't understand how to take my input string and print it out with right-alignment

Tags: java

[image]I'm taking a string input and prompt the user for score values, which the user can input up to 5 scores and no less than 1. I don't understand how to take that string and print it out so there are no more commas and they are right aligned.

This is what I have so far:

```
//user inputs for number of students
    numStudents = UtilsKS.readInt("Enter number of students: ", false);                                

    //while loop for correct input of students
    while (numStudents <= 0 || numStudents > 12) { 
        System.out.print("ERROR: must be 1-12, ");

        numStudents = UtilsKS.readInt("Enter number of students: ", false);
    }

    // user input for student score using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        stuScores = UtilsKS.readString("Enter comma-separated test score for student " + (i+1) + ": ", false);

    }

    //initializing testscore to = what scores are inputed per student
    for (int t=0; t<numStudents; t++) {
        testScores[t] = stuScores;
    }    

    // setting up turning string into separate arrays and trimming them
    array1 = stuScores.split(",");

    for (int i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
        score[i] = Integer.parseInt(array1[i].trim());
    }

    //outputs
    System.out.println( String.format("%10s", header)); 
    System.out.println( String.format("%10.2f", score));
```

My main question is how do I take the inputs and properly format them to print?

Comment: Can you put an example of the actual output that you have right now and the one you want to have ?

Comment: @RobertoFernandez the outputs need to look like that

Comment: You already use String.format in your code.  Format the int scores so that they take up 9 positions.